# How to make text search and similarity computation across millions of records efficient in python

Tags: python, performance, full-text-search, similarity, processing-efficiency

I have two tables containing 2 million records each. One has the item names and other item description along with other attributes. I have to match each item in table 1 with each description in table 2 to find maximum similarity matches. So basically, for each of 2 million items, I have to scan the other table to find best match. That makes 2 million * 2 million computations! How do I go about doing that in python efficiently? As it stands now, it will take years to compute.

Right now the approach I am following is regex search by splitting each item name into words in a list and then checking if the word is contained in description or not.If yes, then I increase the match count by 1 and using that I calculate similarity.

So my question(s) is :

1. How to make my computations faster? Use multithreading, split
   data or anything like this?
2. Any other similarity algorithm that will work here? Please note that
   I have description on the other side, so cosine similarity etc don't
   work because of differing number of words.

Comment: What is a table technically?

Comment: I am fetching the data from mongodb and putting it into python dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/0.1) package to calculate the Levenshtein Distance for similarity.

From the documentation:

> Comparing lists of strings can also be useful for computing
>   similarities between sentences, paragraphs, etc., in articles or
>   books, as for plagiarism recognition:

```
>>> sent1 = ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
>>> sent2 = ['the', 'lazy', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'crazy', 'dog']
>>> distance.levenshtein(sent1, sent2)
3
```

Or the [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0) package:

```
>>> distance('Levenshtein', 'Lenvinsten')
4

>>> distance('Levenshtein', 'Levensthein')
2
>>> distance('Levenshtein', 'Levenshten')
1
>>> distance('Levenshtein', 'Levenshtein')
0
```

Comment: I tried this. But as I said there is description on the other end, it is not giving me good similarity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NLTK as well.

```
from nltk import *
reference = 'DET NN VB DET JJ NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
test    = 'DET VB VB DET NN NN NN IN DET NN'.split()
print(accuracy(reference, test))
print edit_distance("rain", "shine")
```

Comment: accuracy function requires reference and test to be of same length. I do not have test strings of same length